# SSRS -OR Condition in Reporting

Tags: reporting-services

i have a report with paramater `@FiscalYear` .
i also have a column `FiscalYear` .

there can records where fiscalyear with NULL VALUE.

i currently have a FILTER Where FiscalYear`LIKE`@FiscalYear 
But i also want to `FiscalYear = NULL LIKE @FiscalYear`

Both conditions should satisfy in dataset filter .
Can any one help me on this

i have tried this but could not find any luck with both conditions.

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING( Fields!Fiscalyear.Value ),Parameters!Fiscalyear.Value,Parameters!Fiscalyear.Value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have used this expression to solve my problem.

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING( Fields!Fiscalyear.Value ),Parameters!Fiscalyear.Value,Fields!Fiscalyear.Value)
```